# TDD в MS VS 9 или 10 на C++

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Добрый день, всем участникам форума!
Может ли кто-нибудь посоветовать какие-нибудь материалы на тему указанную в заголовке? Примеры, описание... Всё, что я ни находил в данном направлении было про С#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TDD на C++ возможен, однако, как и все прочее в C++, не обходится без костылей.

Причины очевидны - отсутствие рефлекшнов, ручная аллокация памяти, разделение на хедеры и файлы с исходным кодом и т.п. *По сути заниматься TDD в C++ - это тоже самое, что заниматься TDD, например, в проекте на C#, где все написано внутри одного большого `unsafe` блока и постоянно вызываются функции из каких-либо сторонних непроверенных библиотек.*

Если это не отбивает желания, то вектор движения должен быть примерно следующим:

- Настроить отдельный проект для тестирования
- Подключить библиотеку юнит-тестирования *(я в своих проектах применял googletest - http://code.google.com/p/googletest/)*)
- Подключить библиотеку для мокинга объектов *(как ни странно, я юзал googlemock - http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/)*
- Настроить отдельные варианты билдов основного проекта для production и для тестирования, при этом очевидно, что исходный проект должен линковаться к проекту для тестирования.

---

**Замечания:**

- В MSVS 9+ есть встроенная поддержка googletest и результат становится удобно интерпретировать.
- В googletest есть отличный макрос `EXPECT_DEATH`, который проверяет, не "упал" ли тест в рантайме, что очень хорошо конкретно для C++ *(т.к порой это единственный способ протестить некоторый C++-код, не использующий исключения).*
- *Отдельные варианты билдов порой бывают просто необходимы для обхода некоторых "костылей" языка.* В моем случае необходимо было проверить, будет ли `assert` в определенном тесте, но, к сожалению, в проекте применялась собственная система `assert`'ов с собственными диалоговыми окнами. И, естественно, это никак не проверялось макросом `EXPECT_ASSERT` из библиотеки googletest. Пришлось в билде для тестирования заменить эти ассерты на стандартные и проверяемые.
- Мокинг в C++ - неблагодарное дело, т.к все функции должны быть объявлены как `virtual`, для того, чтобы их можно было заменить на соответсвующие mock'и. *Здесь опять спасает идеология раздельных билдов и дефайны в стиле `TEST_MOCKABLE_METHOD`.*
- Лично у меня вначале TDD в C++ очень сильно замедляло работу, большей частью из-за "накладных расходов" и отсутствия поддержки идеологии в IDE. *Не знаю, мне кажется, вряд ли эта ситуация сильно изменится в ближайшее время.*

---

**Что почитать:**

Я начал бы с reference book к библиотекам googletest и googlemock, там также есть дополнительные референсы по теме.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрим)

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь [boost test library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html), в частности [unit test framework](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf.html).

Comment: Почему-то когда я пытаюсь перейти по этой ссылке: http://www.boost.org/libs/test , чтобы получить последнюю версию библиотеки, то получаю редирект на http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html , где не могу найти ссылку для скачивания =( Мож я не туда смотрю?)

Comment: @myasnik90 Самый простой способ - скачать весь `boost` последней версии, запустить `bootstrap` для его сборки (соберется в том числе и `boost::test`) и потом использовать собранную библиотеку в своем проекте. *Если что, то буст использует `boost::test` для самотестирования, так что хорошие примеры использования можно найти там же.*